# It is possible to force SSL only in specific views in RoR3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, https

I'm using a payment gem that needs to use https for its view.

Can I force the app to use https for only those 3-4 views and leave my others views using plain http?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `force_ssl` method in your controller. See the docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html).

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  force_ssl only: [:create, :update]
end
```

Comment: ok so imagine I go to create and after create I redirect to another controller. HTTPS stays ON, how can I avoid that behaviour?

Comment: Simplest thing I can think of is manually switching back in the redirect: `redirect_to url_for(@page).sub("https:", "http:")`. There is probably a cleaner way of doing that by passing more options to `redirect_to`, but I couldn't tell from my quick glance at the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html